# how to create a sql temp table and insert data into it using a sql command (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have cerated a `c#` form containing a `gridview`. I want to insert the selected row data to a temp table on button click. I've tried like this but its not working. Its shows the error:

> String or Binary Data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

below is my code:-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        int i = 0;
        List<int> ChkedRow = new List<int>();

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value) == true)
            {
                ChkedRow.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if (ChkedRow.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Items to view report");
            return;
        }

        foreach (int j in ChkedRow)
        {
            String ConnectionString1 = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

            cnnStr = @"create table ##gridtemp (itmcod varchar(7)) INSERT INTO ##gridtemp (itmcod)
                        VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["title"].Value.ToString() + "');";

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
                {

                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(cnnStr, cs))
                    {
                        cs.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Records Added Succesfully");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to insert in a temp table?

Comment: the main table contains a large number of records. I need only the filtered records for reports

Comment: The error description is very clear: `dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["title"].Value.ToString()` is a string larger then 7 chars.

Comment: "String or Binary Data would be truncated.The statemnt has been terminated" means that you are trying to enter a larger input than the field capacity. Change the char(7) to a larger input

Comment: how to correct this

Comment: Change "itmcod varchar(7)" to "itmcod varchar(max)"

Comment: ok thank a lot guys

Comment: but the code is not creating a temptable, we want to create it seperately

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("create table ##gridtemp (itmcod varchar(MAX))", conn1);
        conn1.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dts = new DataTable();
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn1);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##gridtemp";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dts);
        conn1.Close();

        int i = 0;
        List<int> ChkedRow = new List<int>();

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value) == true)
            {
                ChkedRow.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if (ChkedRow.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Items to view report");
            return;
        }

        foreach (int j in ChkedRow)
        {
            String ConnectionString1 = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

            cnnStr = @"INSERT INTO ##gridtemp (itmcod)
                        VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["itmcod"].Value.ToString() + "');";

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
                {

                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(cnnStr, cs))
                    {
                        cs.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Records Added Succesfully");
    }
}
```